# Extract images in a .docx file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docx

How to extract images in a docx file line by line in Ruby?

Couldn't find any gem that does this.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy without any library (or at least not a gem specific for this purpose)

You should :

- unzip the document (preferably in memory)
- You can then extract the content of : `word/media/*`

where * would be all files.

For example, you will have :

```
word/media/image1.png
word/media/image2.png
```

Comment: Some of the images can be in `word/media/embeddings` also.  This is at least true for embedded Visio files.

Answer (score -1):

Using Jasper report, you can generate in a variety of document formats including HTML, PDF, Excel, OpenOffice and Word(DOCX).

In my opinion, you don't need gem, It's simple to Integrate jasper report to your project. following : https://www.sitepoint.com/create-great-reports-jasperreports/
This example is for rails, but it works well for a ruby project too.

Notice: You need a Java Virtual Machine installed in server side.